# How to create LinkedList (nodes) out of scope? C#

Tags: c#, hint

I am having difficulty in understanding how to convert a number into a linked list, or at least I am just confused as to how they persist outside of the function they were created in. The problem is leetcode's Problem #2 in C#.

The problem is :

> You are given two non-empty linked lists representing two non-negative integers. The digits are stored in reverse order, and each of their nodes contains a single digit. Add the two numbers and return the sum as a linked list. You may assume the two numbers do not contain any leading zero, except the number 0 itself.

The set up is :

```
// Definition for singly-linked list.
 public class ListNode {
     public int val;
     public ListNode next;
     public ListNode(int val=0, ListNode next=null) {
         this.val = val;
         this.next = next;
     }
}

public class Solution {
    public ListNode AddTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        
    }
}
```

My solution involves a lengthy conversion of the linked list into an integer and then adding the two integers together.

But I am having trouble grasping how I am supposed to `return the sum as a linked list`. Specifically I am having difficulty understanding how the linked list will exist outside of the `AddTwoNumbers` and how exactly do I construct the ListNodes themselves?

For example, the first prompt is for {2, 4, 3} and {5, 6, 4} equaling 708, then reversed to 807.

I am confused on how to proceed after getting 807 as an integer. Specifically, do I need to figure out how many ListNodes I need to initialize first? Or how will all the ListNodes exist outside of the function they are created in (scope)?

Thank you for any insight into this problem, and your time.

Comment: Just a hint: you don’t need to convert anything. Think how you’d do addition on paper and how that relates to having numbers as linked lists. If you don’t know how to instantiate an object, or return one, then you will need to refer to a tutorial on C#

Comment: Elaborating on the hint. If the lists store the digits in reverse order, then the first item in each list represents the _ones_, the second, the _tens_ and so on. If the first item in one list is 5, and the first in the other list is 7, the 5+7 is 2, carry 1, so the first item in the result list should be 2.